# Qt завершить процессы запущенные с помощью QtConcurrent

Tags: c++, qt

Добрый день!

Имеется класс, в котором, с помощью QtConcurrent запускается метод с бесконечным циклом.
Примерно такой:

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::myMethod);
}

void MyClass::myMethod()
{
    while (true) {
        QThread::sleep(10);
        // Тут делаем кучу полезных и важных дел...
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно и быстро, завершить этот поток?

Ибо сейчас, всё работает нормально, ровно до тех пор пока я не вызову exit(0) из MainWindow, после этого программа зависает, очевидно ожидая, когда этот бесконечный процесс закончится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#run) написано:

> Note that the `QFuture` returned by `QtConcurrent::run()` does not support canceling, pausing, or progress reporting. The `QFuture` returned can only be used to query for the running/finished status and the return value of the function.

То-есть, `QtConcurrent` не поддерживает остановку.

Потому стоит добавить какой-то флаг, и перед закрытием приложения его переключать:

```
while(true) {
    if(aborted) {
        return;
    }
    // куча полезных дел
}
```

И перед `exit(0)`:

```
aborted = true;
```

Comment: боюсь, это не очень поможет - там есть sleep. Нужно ещё ещё прервать.

Comment: @KoVadim а какая версия Qt? Я сейчас попробую, но мне кажется что в пятой это поведение не поменяли.

Comment: ну так это не к Qt относиться, а к работе с потоками вообще.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну так в реальном коде sleep нет, надеюсь

Comment: @Lol4t0 Прошу прощения, чем так плох sleep? Мне надо чтобы одно и тоже действие выполнялось каждые 10 секунд. Есть лучшие варианты чем бесконечный while со sleep?

Comment: использование sleep в потоках (не главном) - это нормально. Абсолютно нормально. Но вот только если поток, который находиться в режиме сна (то есть в sleep) нужно завершиться, то sleep нужно прервать. Но sleep - это особая операция (ну не настолько - таких функций на самом деле много - recv, select, send), которые можно прервать, послав сигнал (только это не то, что в Qt называется сигналом). Но это в линуксе. В винде тоже работает, но только не уверен по по поводу сигналов.

Comment: Согласен что `sleep` вообще-то и не плох, но, например тут, если надо каждые 10 секунд запускать, то лучше использовать [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details).

Comment: А вот далеко не факт. Некоторые алгоритмы легче сделать на базе потока. К тому же код, запускаемый таймером будет работать внутри главного потока, а там тежелые операции лучше не делать.

Comment: @ПавелВершинин, sleep в Qtconcurrent::run - плохая идея. как и бесконечный цикл. Потому что Qtconcurrent::run исполняется внутри пула потоков, мощность которого ограничена. Если запустить достаточно много таких задач, то некоторые могут вообще не получить управление никогда.

Comment: Кстати говоря, sleep заменяется на QWaitCondition c ограничением по времени ожидания для создания нужного эффекта в вашем случае

Answer (score 2):

Из QtConcurrent::run() никак не выйти посредством QFuture. Только с использованием какой-нибудь переменной (флага), защищённой мьютексом. Ну а на выходе из программы, дабы не случился крах по причине всё ещё не завершившегося потока, добавьте: QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone()